# Compilation Optimisation issue of a Haskell project

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have the impression my Haskell project recompiles all the files each time I do a `stack build` even if I have changed only a Haskell files that has no dependencies with the majority of the other ones.

Am I having a setting that forces to recompile everything or maybe it's the behaviour by default ? How can I optimise it ?

I see `Compiling .... [Optimisation flags changed]` all the time also, maybe it's related to my issue...

Comment: It will usually recompile all flags that *depend* on the changed file. So if file `B` imports `A`, and you change `A`, it will recompile `B` as well. This can result in a "chain" of recompilations. If `C` for example imports `B`, then if you rewrite `A`, eventually `C` will need to recompile as well, since `B` was recompiled.

Comment: You can use `--force-dirty` to recompile the entire project.

Comment: what it 's doing is that if B import A but I only change B, it recompiles also A... actually it recompiles everything all the times.... That's what I was trying to explain... maybe I have a --force-dirty hidden somewhere.. I'm going to look at it..

Comment: Didn't find anything about force-dirty in my config... btw I have the impression my IDE (Intellij is not recompiling everything though...), it looks like it's only in my terminal (not sure about it...)...

Comment: Could it be due to my IDE ?? like it is changing something somehow ? I'm going to do some tests

Comment: This is my IDE !! somehow it's changing something in all my files...

Comment: @NicolasHenin Are you using intellij-haskell? Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Never mind, I just decided to use a separate directory for building with it's own `.stack-work`. I think when `.stack-work` is shared with the IDE is when we get this problem. This building directory just contains symlinks to the source files so that doing `stack build` in the building directory will work.